# How can I make a list of items appear daily in a recycler view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-4.4-kitkat

I want them to represent a list of daily habits, which can be checked of during the day, and will appear again the next day. In what direction should I research this?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to do this. Either you store your daily habits in database and fetch it from there or store your daily habits in `SharedPreferences` and get your data inside onCreate in Activity.

To save your data inside SharedPreferences you can use code below:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Alex");
editor.putInt("habit", "Start Coding");
editor.apply();
```

And to retrieve data you should use code below inside onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "Empty");//"Empty" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("habit", "Empty");
```